# What are the online blood testing services that allow to pick and choose exactly what test you want?

Tags: blood, blood-tests, diagnostics

I know there are now several competitive online blood test companies that offer a menu of bundled blood test services in the US.  I am looking for a US based service that would disaggregate their bundled services so you could pick and choose what test you want.  I know Theranos offers that service through Walgreens stores at specific locations.  But, they are nowhere near where I live.

I actually did find such a company about a month ago.  I did not bookmark the site.  And, I have googled searched for it very extensively for a very long time with no success.  It seems this company disappeared.  Maybe someone knows of a similar company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow today I had a bit more luck in addressing my own question.  It seems that many of the online blood testing services do offer tests on a disaggregated basis.  Their more popular products are bundled tests that include some of the typical overall blood tests for an annual physical.  But, several of those enterprises also offer unbundled tests of more esoteric yet very important tests such as for C-Reactive protein and Fibrinogen.  The latter is a very good check to see how granular can you go in terms of specific independent blood tests you can order from such services.  Today, I found two companies that passed that check.  One is Accesa Labs that operates through Quest Diagnostics.  The other one is Health Tests Direct (HTD).  HTD is actually very interesting because they operate through both Quest Diagnostics and LabCorp.  As a result, HTD allows you to do some comparative shopping in terms of test prices between those two market leaders.

Although the above answer is reasonably inclusive, it does not preclude that others may uncover specific companies that could be equal if not superior to the two I mentioned above.

This is a short update as of December 2017.  As we know Theranos has run into all sorts of legal and regulatory troubles since I first wrote this answer.  They are now I think very much out of this business.  After considering many online lab testing providers I recently chose Personalabs.com.  They allowed you to select your blood test on a disaggregated basis as well as any other online competitors.  What differentiated them is that their website and their blood test selections were so much clearer than competitors.  They operated through Quest Diagnostics and LabCorp just like the other better services.  Interestingly enough, I got my lab test results through Personalabs.com within 5 days.  Yet, over 10 days later, I still could not get the same from Quest Diagnostics (QD).  I am still interested in getting the results from QD just to check that their interpretation of the results (healthy acceptable range of values) are the same as for Personalabs.

Comment: If the lab takes more than 30 days to give you the results, please [report an infraction of the HIPAA requirements](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5601/31)

Comment: Franck, thanks much for the regulatory framework reference.  Hopefully, this won't be needed.  I understand Quest Diagnostics and LabCorp typically complete their blood test analysis within just a few days.  They conduct those on behalf of the mentioned online blood test service intermediaries.  Also, I think Theranos is pushing around the industry in a good way by making their tests readily available.  Unfortunately, their geographical coverage is minimal so far.

Comment: +1 for making me aware of this. And you really should accept this answer.

Comment: Carey I was not aware I could accept my own answer.  But, I gather I can.